# Style multiple option values using jquery: Code works for a few option values only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select box that holds fonts for styling

```
<select class="gfonts">
  <option value="arial" style="font-family:arial;">Arial</option>
  <option value="tahoma" style="font-family:tahoma;">Calibri</option>
  <option value="segoe" style="font-family:segoe;">Segoe</option>
</select>
```

The options are styled properly and you can preview the font before applying it. But I have 700+ fonts and the    ***option style(font-family)*** is not working.
 have tried this code but its only working if the fonts are like 200. above that, the preview won't work

```
 var fontarray=allfonts.split(",");
 var html='';
 for(x=0;x<fontarray.length;x++)
      {
 html += '<option class="f'+x+'" style="font-family:'+fontarray[x]+';"     value="' + fontarray[x] + '">' + fontarray[x] + '</option>';
     }
 $('.font_type').append(html);
```

}

Please note, all fonts are loaded and 'var allfonts' is a comma sepated string.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No, But i notice when you click the select box, the fonts are being rendered slowly, meaning the browser is struggling to style the options if they are many. Thats why it totally fails to style 700 option values

Comment: @nikhil , I cant create a fiddle coz the code is too large, but i have attached a screen shot. If you need clarification please ask.

Comment: i think it's big process for browser , maybe using font in images is better idea?

Comment: What do you mean font in images sir?

Comment: write your fonts to a lots of small images (with php scripts or by hand!)  and then use images instead of text in your select box  (but not default html selectbox because its not support image , you can use Jquery UI  http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render )

Comment: i forget to ask you! where is that 700 fonts !! did you import them by using css ( @font-face ) ?

Comment: Ok, Its a project I am doing for a client. I had even suggested using list. But he categorically insists on <select></select>. The select box have many events associated with onchange and also , other functions are dependent on it. Its an online product design app. I am checking the jquery UI . But a solution based on my select box will be much safer for me. My idea is, if we append the styled options in groups to the select box, maybe it would be lighter for browser, But I dont know how to achive that..

Comment: They are google fonts, I have called all of them using jquery call, They are hosted by google, not on my server

Answer (score 1):

From a user standpoint loading 700 fonts into a list makes no sense, it's not like I am ever going to go through all that list. Your client might want to revise that strategy.

But in order to put less pressure on the browser you could try populating the list as you scroll through it rather than loading the entire list on load time. I believe there are some modules like waypoints(http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) which you could use but you would have to investigate further.

Comment: Vlad, The reason we are loading all those fonts is because its a product design tool e.g. business cards, banners e.t.c. so as to give the client more fonts to choose from. Secondly, we are calling all google fonts and there is no way to emit some results. waypoints looks like a good solution. let me try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var fontarray=allfonts.split(",");
var html='';
var i = fontarray.length/100;
var j = fontarray.length/100;
for(x=0;x<fontarray.length;x++) {
   html += '<option class="f'+x+'" style="font-family:'+$.trim(fontarray[x])+';" value="' + $.trim(fontarray[x]) + '">' + $.trim(fontarray[x]) + '</option>';
   if(x == (i-(j--))*100){
       $('.font_type').append(html);
       html = "";
   }
}
$('.font_type').append(html);
```

Comment: Yes they are, see the attachment above. after I run your code

Comment: Can you also share the html from the inspect tab of the select tag. I think there is some mistake in the html of that select option.

Comment: Yes, above is the html of the select box, those are the options and their inline styles.

Comment: Hey can you tell me why some of the option do not contain any font family. And i think your problem was due to the space when applying the font family. Please try my latest updated code.

Comment: Some options are found in the textbox and are not styled, The spacing is not affecting the styles. You realize that if I reduce the fonts to like 100, they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to solve my issue based on the solutions you provided. I have added the load fonts event in a countdown so that they are loaded slowly and allow the browser to load them without strain.

```
 var count = 0, timer = setInterval(function() {

var co = ((count++)+1);
console.log(co);

   // $('.f'+co).css('font-family',fontarray[co]);
html = '<option class="f'+co+'" style="font-family:'+fontarray[co]+';" value="' + fontarray[co] + '">' + fontarray[co] + '</option>';    
if(count == 715)
    {
 clearInterval(timer); 
    }
    $('.font_type').append(html);           

}, 20);

 }
```

Hope this helps someone in future. cheers